# Serving Angular dist into Tomcat is reading routes as folders

Tags: java, angular, tomcat

I had some troubles with CORS (i couldn't communicate angular serve port 4200 with my tomcat 8080 port) so i moved my angular project into my java WebContent and now i'm serving directly the dist folder (so i solve my CORS issues). I thought that it would work but after the first call of the index.html (index redirect me to my default route) if i try to change my route the browser says not found. I've been working 3 days on this issue but i'm lost.

Comment: Are you using  Spring boot ?

Comment: I'm not using Spring boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `HashLocationStrategy` to tell Angular to resolve the route.

```
import {HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy} from "@angular/common";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   ...
  ],
  imports: [
...
  ],
  providers: [
...
    {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy},
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: It works, but i will have any problem if i try to communicate my front with my back?

Comment: You will not have a problem. Since Angular app is a single page application, all is done within your index.html. Calling YOUR_DOMAINE/resource, tomcat will try to find the resource within its root folder and will not find it. this is why you have the error. Using HashLocationStrategy tell  Angular to resolve the route within the index.html

Comment: Radouane ROUFID talked about Spring. It would be a better solution instead of hash location?

Comment: You have to keep hashLocation any way.